# How to require a specific input length and a 0-9 requirement using pattern attribute?

Tags: html

I need to combine two patterns, however once I put them together using | both of them won't work.

How do you combine such patterns?

This is for an input field (on a form). I want to make the user type 13 characters precisely as well as require numbers only.

I tried:
" pattern="**(.){13,13}**" maxlength="13" required>

This works. It requires 13 characters but also allows letters.

But once I add the second pattern for requiring numbers only, both patterns won't work.

" pattern="**(.){13,13}|[0-9]***" maxlength="13" required>

I expect it to require 13 letters, using numbers only, but it doesn't require neither.

Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you use some javascript to do that ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/469419/6809926

Comment: @antoinF If possible, I prefer to do this without javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line:

```
pattern=".{12,13}[0-9]"
```

It should only accept exactly 13 numbers, and no letters.